# Pushing values from one array into a Multi-Dimensional Array and got an Error

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
function studentClasses() {
    var names = [];
    var course = [];
    var sortCourse = [];
    var uniqueCourse = [];
    var nameCourse = [];

    while (records.readNextRecord()) {
        var studentNames = records.getStudentName();
        var studentCourse = records.getStudentCourseNumber();

        names.push(studentNames);
        course.push(studentCourse);
        sortCourse.push(studentCourse);
        sortCourse.sort();
    }
    // sort a list of courses to find the unique courses
    for (var i = 0; i < sortCourse.length; i++) {
        if (sortCourse[i] !== sortCourse[i - 1]) {
            uniqueCourse.push(sortCourse[i]);
        }
    }

    uniqueCourse.sort;
    nameCourse.length = uniqueCourse.length;

    // create multi-d array containing names for a certain course
    for (var x = 0; x < uniqueCourse.length; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < course.length; y++) {
            if (uniqueCourse[x] === course[y]) {
                nameCourse[x].push(names[y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code that I am working on and I am getting an error of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…)

I have two arrays ("**course**" & "**names**") that contain information that have data in specific indexes.  I am trying to compare information from my "**uniqueCourse**" array to my "**course**" array and if they match, the index place from "**course**" would then be used to call the information from the index place in "**names**".

Here is where the problem is:
When I try to push "**names[y]**" into a multidimensional array that would have a length equal to uniqueCourse (which is 5 if the code is ran), I get the error.

***Question:***
Why am I getting an undefined error when I try to use the code

```
nameCourse[x].push(names[y]);
```

to push the information from **names** to **nameCourse** with x being the corresponding level that I want those names to be stored?

I want:

```
nameCourse = [ [however many names called from names[y]],
               [however many names called from names[y]],
               [however many names called from names[y]],
               [however many names called from names[y]],
               [however many names called from names[y]] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `nameCourse` array is filled with `undefined`
You need to initialize nameCourse[x] to be an array and only then push into it.
Something like below:

`nameCourse = new Array(uniqueCourse.length).fill(0);`

Comment: So is doing something like 
    nameCourse[x] = [ ]

Comment: yep. same thing